# Do Adam and Eve have belly buttons?

Tags: genesis, creation

Every one born has umbilical cord that is cut off at birth which leaves a belly button mark.  Since Adam and Eve wasn't conceived and went through  normal birth like all of us, there is no umbilical cord to be cut off - therefore no belly button.
I just wasn't sure of this as Adam and Eve serves as prototype of mankind  and should we should reflect their image even though they were created as  adults.  Not sure what others think about this or if even this crossed your mind. Just curious what others have to say about this.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  The answer to your question is: NO - definitely NOT!  Please ensure that questions are about a specific passage of the Bible.

Comment: See the book ['Omphalos' (Umbilicus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphalos_(book)#:~:text=Omphalos%3A%20An%20Attempt%20to%20Untie,would%20appear%20to%20be%20older). by Phillip Gosse (1857) which argues that the fossil record is not an evidence of evolution and who named his book accordingly, in the same vein as this question. (Up-voted +1.) The book was published two years before Darwin's 'Origin of Species'.